# Live Editing in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

Is there a way to live edit ASP.NET in VS2012 the way that you can live edit AngularJS in WebStorm? I saw and installed [AutoF5](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hongyes/archive/2011/11/03/introducing-to-autof5-nuget-package-live-editing-in-asp-net.aspx) but the project seems to have been abandoned and isn't working anymore.

I'm currently working with the [AngularJS SPA Template](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5af151b2-9ed2-4809-bfe8-27566bfe7d83) and would like to see my changes as I'm learning AngularJS.

P.S. the only view I have in my document is source. And even if I could actually see what it looked like, it still wouldn't be what the user would see when the page is rendered.

Comment: My question has been marked down a point. Could you give me an explanation why?

Comment: Not sure if it works for VS2012, but Web Essentials works great in 2013.

Comment: @DavidG Can't seem to find documentation on how to actually use this. I've install it and the package "ASP.NET and Web Tools 2012.2" and haven't noticed any changes except for the option edit some solution settings and minify .js files...

Comment: @DavidG does not work from VS and editing the HTML from the browser tools in Chrome doesn't seem to take effect either. Neither does it change when editing CSS

Comment: I think the live editing is done the other way round. Edit the cshtml/css files and the browser updates automatically.

Comment: Yes, I've just watched a video of Mads doing that in 2012, but it doesn't seem to be working for me. I guess I'll just have to stick with browser inspector for now. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the [Browser Inspector in Visual Studio](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudiouk/archive/2012/11/19/visual-studio-2012-page-inspector.aspx). You can edit and see as you go...

Comment: yes, It seems possible by pressing Ctrl+Alt+Enter once you've made edits, correct?